# Call controller/action in event listener

Tags: php, symfony, controller, listener

I want to run a process in background when user login. So I create a process in a login listener.

Here is my code.

```
public function onLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
      $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

      if($user)
      {
        $userid= $user->getId();
        echo $userid;
        $process = new Process('php d:wamp/www/jobologic/app/console JJJJ:RRRR'." ".$userid); 
        $process->start();

      }
    }
```

after the process start in background. I want user see the homepage of the website. What should I do after the $process->start()function?

Comment: Redirect to the homepage...Thats all

Comment: Could you be more precise? I'm really a rookie. Thx. @User016

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a form login, you could configure a default target path and force it with the following configuration:

```
firewalls:
    myfirewall:
        # ...
        form_login:
            # ...
            always_use_default_target_path: true
            default_target_path:            /
```

Configuration reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html

Comment: I have another issue is that when I write like this, it will redirect to the homepage. But the process doesn't run in background. Do you have any ideas? Thank you for helping me

Comment: It's probably not gonna be detached from the main process (so when your main request finishes the process you've started will die). This is not a common thing to do. If you need asynchronous process, use message/job queues.